# How to save the changes permanently in fxml file while adding menuItems through code

Tags: javafx, scenebuilder

The following piece of code works good as long as the window is **open**. Menuitem added through code is visible in dropdown as expected

```
 @FXML
        public static MenuButton youradd;

 @FXML  
    public void static addingMenuItem()
    {
            yourAdd.getItems().addAll(new MenuItem(newName));
    }
```

**But the issue is** , when the particular stage or window is closed, the added menuitem disappers in the dropdown. I want the menuitems added to be stored permanently in the fxml code so that the menuitems are visible everytime i run the stage

NOTE: MenuButton has been created through scenebuilder. but adding MenuItems through code

Comment: it not a practical method..i think you can do it by using database or file..you maintain regarding information in it and use it according your need.